# WP Как в админке рубрики вывести поле со списком всех назначенных постов этой рубрики?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как в админ части Wordpress кастомной рубрики вывести список постов которым назначена данная рубрика ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал как-то так

```
// Show posts for some vendor
add_action('admin_init', 'vendors_custom_fields', 1);
function vendors_custom_fields() {
    add_action('vendors_edit_form_fields', 'category_custom_fields_form');
}

function category_custom_fields_form($tag) {?>

    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row">Компании с текущим производителем:</th>
        <td>
            <?php
            $t_id = $tag->term_id;
            $cat_meta = get_option("category_$t_id");
            
            
            $args = array(
                'cat' => $t_id,  
            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <p><?php echo get_the_title() ?></p>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php esc_html_e( 'У такого производителя нету назначенных компаний' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Но это работает не правильно. Хотя вроде как в $t_id хранит id нужной категории, а указывает что постов нету

Comment: Где "вывести"? .

Comment: в админке категории. По типу произвольного поля

Comment: В админке эти цифры и так выводятся.

Comment: @SeVlad он же список хочет

Comment: @KAGGDesign аа.. да, я протупил :)

Comment: Наверное мне стоит объяснить зачем мне необходимо выводить список связанных постов в категории. - На сайте используется плагин ACF, в нем для внутренней перелинковки постов разных рубрик заведено доп. поле ACF [Объект записи][1] в котором идет вывод  всех постов. Но что бы контент менеджер мог правильно перелинковать посты хочу показывать ему какие посты были выбраны к определенной рубрике.                                                                              
[1]: https://acfwp.ru/obekt-zapisi-post-object/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы неправильно выбираете посты, для того что бы выбрать посты указанной таксономии вы должны выбирать их по таксономиям а не по категориям

```
$args = [
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => $tag->taxonomy,
            'terms' => $t_id,
        ],
    ],
];

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```